# Target a certain page within wordpress backend (admin) i.e. Pages > About

Tags: functions, wp-admin, pages

How can i progammatically see if the page that is currently open in the wordpress admin is 'About-Me';

I wish to run specific functions depending on the page the user is editing in the wordpress-admin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$post` global.

Somewhere inside of a function, hooked in appropriately to the post-edit screen:

```
// Globalize the $post variable
global $post;
// check to see that we are on a page, with a title "About Me"
if ( 'page' == $post->post_type && 'About Me' == $post->post_title ) {
    // This is the "About Me" page;
    // do something
}
```