# How to select a page within admin?

Tags: functions, admin, actions

How does one apply an action to one particular page within admin?

I've added a bunch of wysiwyg editors to one page ("Home") and now I don't need the main editor. But the function below - of course - removes the editor from all pages:

```
function remove_editor_from_home_page() {

  remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'remove_editor_from_home_page' );
```

How can I target the Home page within admin by name - "Home" - or by page_id?

This other WPSE answer doesn't want to work for me:
[Target a certain page within wordpress backend](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32232/target-a-certain-page-within-wordpress-backend-admin-i-e-pages-about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'wpse_57924_remove_editor' );
function wpse_57924_remove_editor( $post )
{
    if ( $post->ID == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) /* or hardcode ID if not front page */ )
        remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'editor' );
}
```

Comment: Works great. Hardcoding the page ID # doesn't, though. Also: how did you determine the string 'page_on_front' for the "Home" page? How do I target other pages by name?

Comment: `page_on_front` is the ID for the "static front page" under Settings > Reading. You can use other properties of `$post` to compare to, like `post_name` (the slug) or `post_title` (the title).